# Redirect url is not working in fetch API

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, cross-domain

I am working on one of the app in which having Login system. there are 4 APIs to hit. In 4rth API I am getting redirect url:

https://xxx-xxx-xx.xx.xxxxx.xx:xxx/xxx?code=af418c3e-b497-40a8-8e19-dbc9da23f885&state=https%3A%2F%2Fapi-iam-stg.map.mandiant.com%3A443%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fsession%2Flogin%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fconsole-iam-stg.ap.mandiant.com%2Fhomepage%26cacheBuster%3D2.0.0_242

When I am calling this API using fetch i am getting following error:

> TypeError: Network request failed at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror
>   (fetch.js:441) at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:546) at
>   XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381) at
>   XMLHttpRequest.js:485 at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit
>   (EventEmitter.js:181) at MessageQueue.__callFunction
>   (MessageQueue.js:266) at MessageQueue.js:103 at MessageQueue.__guard
>   (MessageQueue.js:231) at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>   (MessageQueue.js:102)

Please help me where i am doing something wrong.... :(

Comment: can you provide some samples of code so we can help ?

Comment: @PanagiotisVrs: this is my code: finalurl is same as above: fetch(finalrl)
   .then((response) => console.log(response))
   .catch((e)=>console.log(e));

Comment: please edit your response above and provide us some code snippets there

Comment: @PanagiotisVrs: I am using same code above for hitting URL mentioned in question, that only I am doing, and it always going in catch block of fetch api